# Running GCC through Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, msbuild, cygwin

I have been writing an app that parses a Visual Studio 2010 solution and attempts to compile it using GCC.

As I built the app I have had it running in a standard console window and I have had no problems (provided you ignore my slight GCC incompatibilities ;)).

The problem comes that when I execute this application under Visual Studio it fires up fine but when it spawns the GCC child processes it reports:

> cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is very confusing as it works fine as a standalone console app.  So has anyone idea what is going on?  What is this "?" library?  Why does it work under the console but not through VStudio?

I dump my PATH env var from inside the build app and it definitely includes my cygwin/bin directory.  Does it get lost immediately after this?  If I run the cygwin bash shell then /usr/bin is in the path.

So what gives?  Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: My two cents: if you need only GCC (and no POSIXness) on Windows, go for MinGW, for example from here: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ This is native GCC that runs on Windows (without, or if you want with Cygwin). You might have a simpler setup without the Cygwin layer, if it's not a necessary part of your app of course.

Comment: @rubenvb:  Alas it HAS to be cygwin :(

Comment: then Rozuur has the answer as to what the problem is. How to solve it is another matter unfortunately. You'll need to make sure the cygwin tools are called from the Cygwin environment. How? I think calling them from Cywgin's (ba)sh.exe would work, but there might be other/better ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this problem with visual studio and I am not sure if this solves your problem, but faced a similar issue when trying to compile a program with cygwin's gcc in windows with emacs. Siince cygwin's gcc.exe is not an executable, but a type of symlink to the actual executable (which is either gcc-3.exe or gcc-4.exe depending on what you have installed). In the BASH shell these symlinks are easily resolved, in cmd.exe they are not.

Comment: This has a large chance of actually being an issue!

Comment: This is a general issue with cygwin when run from cmd.exe.

Comment: @Rozuur: Cheers this does appear to be the issue.  What a pain.  I'm going to run a few more tests to make sure but I suspect you'll be getting a further 315 points from me :)

Comment: @Goz I hope this to be the issue :)

Comment: @Rozuur: Yeah that appears to have been my problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Run [SysInternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see what files are failing to load?

Comment: Otherwise, sysinternals depends.exe can also be of great use.

Comment: True, but if you are twiddling with paths and whatever it's often difficult to get Depends to show you what's wrong and why whereas ProcMon will show you the exact paths that are being tried and which files are failing to load...

Comment: Point of information: depends.exe is not a Sysinternals tool.